# MySQL: To exclude some results based on specified conditions

Tags: mysql

I am stuck at some problem. The problem has two tables, namely hackers and challenges.
Here is the schema:

```
Hackers(hacker_id: int, name string)
Challenges(challenge_id: int, hacker_id int)
```

I am trying to write a query to print the hacker_id, name, and the total number of challenges created by each student. Sort your results by the total number of challenges in descending order. If more than one student created the same number of challenges, then sort the result by hacker_id. If more than one student created the same number of challenges and the count is less than the maximum number of challenges created, then exclude those students from the result.

Here is my query:

```
select hackers.hacker_id , 
       hackers.name , 
       count(challenges.challenge_id) as challenges_created 
       from 
       hackers left join  challenges 
       on 
       hackers.hacker_id = challenges.hacker_id  
       having 
       count(challenges_created) >= max(challenges_created) 
       order by challenges_created desc, hackers.hacker_id asc
```

I am getting wrong output!
Please tell me where I am getting wrong!

Sample Input :

Hackers Table:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fpaD.png) 
Challengers Table :[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7SuW.png)

```
Sample Output:
21283  Angela  6
88255  Patrick  5
96196  Lisa  1
```

Comment: `>= max` doesn't make much sense. by definition max() returns the largest value in the set, so there's no way any other value could be LARGER than this value.

Comment: So how do I exclude those entries which are having a count greater than 2 but less than maximum( last line of the question)

Comment: Please, at least make a consistent sentence: Sort *your* results ... : it looks like a student exercice.

Comment: Sample Input :
    
    Hackers Table:[image given below][1] 
    Challengers Table :[image given below][2] 
     
    Sample Output:
    21283  Angela  6
    88255  Patrick  5
    96196  Lisa  1  
    
    [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8fpaD.png
    [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/L7SuW.png

Answer (score 1):

It's a crazy requirement to solve in mysql only. With CTE (not supported by mysql) you could reuse your query:

```
with tmp as (
    select h.hacker_id, h.name, count(1) as challenges_created
    from hackers h
    left join challenges c on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
    group by h.hacker_id, h.name
    order by challenges_created desc, h.hacker_id asc 
), max_challenges_created as (
    select max(challenges_created) as challenges_created
    from tmp
), count_per_challenges_created as (
    select challenges_created, count(1) as c
    from tmp
    group by challenges_created
)
select *
from tmp
cross join max_challenges_created m
left join count_per_challenges_created c on c.challenges_created = tmp.challenges_created
where tmp.challenges_created = m.challenges_created
   or c.c = 1
```

http://rextester.com/XGYQ11641

In MySQL you can't even use a temporary table, because you couldn't use it multiple times in one query. So you have to copy&paste the same query three times (and hope that mysql will execute it only once using cache):

```
select *
from (
    select h.*, count(1) as challenges_created
    from hackers h
    left join challenges c on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
    group by h.hacker_id
    order by challenges_created desc, h.hacker_id 
) tmp
cross join (
    select max(challenges_created) as challenges_created
    from (
        select h.*, count(1) as challenges_created
        from hackers h
        left join challenges c on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
        group by h.hacker_id
        order by challenges_created desc, h.hacker_id asc
    ) tmp
) m
left join (
    select challenges_created, count(1) as c
    from (
        select h.*, count(1) as challenges_created
        from hackers h
        left join challenges c on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
        group by h.hacker_id
        order by challenges_created desc, h.hacker_id asc
    ) tmp
    group by challenges_created
) c on c.challenges_created = tmp.challenges_created
where tmp.challenges_created = m.challenges_created
   or c.c = 1
```

http://rextester.com/IDUMRB49795

Answer (score 1):

Try start solving smallest part of the query and keep joining them.
You can try my code which is in SQL(Oracle)

```
SELECT h.hacker_id, 
       h.name, 
       COUNT(c.challenge_id) AS challenge_count
FROM Hackers h
JOIN Challenges c ON c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name
HAVING challenge_count = 
    (SELECT COUNT(challenge_id) AS count_max
     FROM Challenges
     GROUP BY hacker_id 
     ORDER BY count_max DESC limit 1)
OR challenge_count IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT c_compare AS c_unique
     FROM (SELECT h2.hacker_id, 
                  h2.name, 
                  COUNT(challenge_id) AS c_compare
           FROM Hackers h2
           JOIN Challenges c ON c.hacker_id = h2.hacker_id
           GROUP BY h2.hacker_id, h2.name) counts
     GROUP BY c_compare
     HAVING COUNT(c_compare) = 1)
ORDER BY challenge_count DESC, h.hacker_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this it's very simple....

```
select
    h.hacker_id,
    h.name
from hackers h, difficulty d, challenges c, submissions s
where
    h.hacker_id=s.hacker_id
and s.challenge_id=c.challenge_id
and d.difficulty_level=c.difficulty_level
and d.score=s.score
group by h.hacker_id, h.name
having count(*)>1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, h.hacker_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the real answer, but the start point for you:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6910c/5

```
SELECT h.hacker_id , 
       h.name , 
       COUNT(challenges.challenge_id) as challenges_created 
FROM  hackers h 
LEFT JOIN challenges 
ON  h.hacker_id = challenges.hacker_id  
GROUP BY h.hacker_id
#HAVING challenges_created >= max(challenges_created) 
ORDER BY challenges_created desc, h.hacker_id asc
```

I've commented out your `HAVING` clause, because can not understand what you are trying to achieve.

Explain please why do you expect only 3 rows in result? Why `Rose` and `Frank` should be excluded from the result set?

Comment: That was the problem statement. May be they had the same count of challenges_created and which is less than maximum.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy when you use multiple joins on the necessary tables. I like to group results as derived tabled for clarity but it can be done without those derived tables too.

```
select hckid, nme
from
(select h.name as nme, h.hacker_id as hckid, cnt
from (select s.hacker_id as hackerid, count(d.score) as cnt
from submissions s
join challenges c
on c.challenge_id = s.challenge_id
join difficulty d
on c.difficulty_level = d.difficulty_level
where d.score = s.score
group by s.hacker_id
having count(d.score) > 1) ft
join hackers h
on ft.hackerid = h.hacker_id) t
order by t.cnt desc, t.hckid asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select hacker_id, name, tmp.challenges_created
from (
    select h.*, count(1) as challenges_created
    from hackers h
    left join challenges c on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
    group by h.hacker_id, h.name
    order by challenges_created desc, h.hacker_id 
) tmp
cross join (
    select max(challenges_created) as challenges_created
    from (
        select h.*, count(1) as challenges_created
        from hackers h
        left join challenges c on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
        group by h.hacker_id, h.name
        order by challenges_created desc, h.hacker_id asc
    ) tmp
) m
left join (
    select challenges_created, count(1) as c
    from (
        select h.*, count(1) as challenges_created
        from hackers h
        left join challenges c on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
        group by h.hacker_id, h.name
        order by challenges_created desc, h.hacker_id asc
    ) tmp
    group by challenges_created
) c on c.challenges_created = tmp.challenges_created
where tmp.challenges_created = m.challenges_created
   or c.c = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.hacker_id, a.name, b.id
  FROM Hackers a
 INNER JOIN (SELECT hacker_id, id
               FROM (SELECT hacker_id, count(challenge_id) AS id
                       FROM Challenges
                      GROUP BY hacker_id) x
               WHERE id = 50
             UNION ALL
             SELECT hacker_id,id
               FROM (SELECT hacker_id, count(challenge_id) AS id
                       FROM Challenges
                      GROUP BY hacker_id) y
              WHERE id IN (SELECT id
                             FROM (SELECT hacker_id, count(challenge_id) AS id
                                     FROM Challenges
                                    GROUP BY hacker_id) x
                            GROUP BY id
                           HAVING count(*) = 1)
            ) b ON a.hacker_id = b.hacker_id
  ORDER BY id DESC, hacker_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a question in hackerranck.com  you can check it [here [link]](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/15-days-of-learning-sql/problem)
in this site you can pass answer by many sql DBMS (oracale,maysql,sqlserver, and DB2)

It's *Work very well* for **SQL-SERVER**

```
with t 
as(
Select  s.hacker_id ,
        s.score,d.Difficulty_level as Difficulty_level, 
        c.Challenge_id
From submissions s 
    inner join Challenges  c  on c.Challenge_id = s.Challenge_id
    inner join Difficulty d on d.Difficulty_level = c.Difficulty_level and d.score = s.score
) 

Select  t.hacker_id, h.name
From t inner join hackers h ON t.hacker_id=h.hacker_id
Where t.score in (Select score from Difficulty)
Group by t.hacker_id,h.name
Having count(t.Challenge_id) > 1
Order by count(t.Challenge_id) desc,t.hacker_id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done in SQL Server
I have joined 2 different selects , the first one uses rank to determine the ones with rank 1 and the second finds duplicates , so in the join result I filtered the result to have either 1st rank or no duplicates (cnt = 1)

```
select s.hacker_id, s.name, s.challenge_created from (
select * ,rank() over (order by challenge_created desc) rn from (
select h.hacker_id, name, count(challenge_id) challenge_created from hackers h 
inner join challenges c on h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
group by h.hacker_id, name) as T) as S
inner join (select A.challenge_created , count(1) cnt from (select h.hacker_id, name, count(challenge_id) challenge_created from hackers h 
inner join challenges c on h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
group by h.hacker_id, name) as A group by A.challenge_created) as O
on s.challenge_created = O.challenge_created
where rn = 1 or O.cnt = 1
order by s.challenge_created desc , hacker_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query works fine in mysql
For having clause condition
I have included the record in which the count is either equal to
maximum number of challenges created OR
the number of challenges created is unique

```
select c.hacker_id,h.name,count(c.challenge_id) as cnt from
challenges c join hackers h
on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
group by c.hacker_id,h.name
having cnt = 
(select max(counts) from (select count(challenge_id) as counts from challenges group by hacker_id) as countstable1) or
cnt in (select counts from (select count(challenge_id) as counts from challenges group by hacker_id) as countstable2 group by counts having count(*)=1)
order by cnt desc,c.hacker_id
```